# Orocommerce application root on AWS

Tags: orocommerce

I have installed the OroCommerce Community Edit, via the AWS marketplace. I would like to generate the public and private keys, for enabling Web API access of the back-end application. Upon SSH'ing into the application, where would I find the root directory of the app? I need to add the keys to the /var directory, within the application, as per the this [doc](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/user-menu/oauth/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root directory is '/var/www/html/commerce'